# DNN javascript error during installation on step 2

Tags: content-management-system, dotnetnuke

I am new to DNN CMS , I have installed the latest version 7.2 but on installation steps
on step 2 while the product is being installed, it keeps loading but no progress.

I opened the firebug and noticed that there are javascript errors [Json parse error].
As below image shows:

[image: DNN Installation Error]

Any idea/solution will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

the latest version of DNN is 7.3.2 abd you probably should be using that one.  Also make sure that the server meets the DNN requirements and that your browser supports javascript

Comment: Thank you Joe. appreciated :)